# How can Elminster, a human, live to over 1000 years old?

Tags: forgotten-realms

[Elminster](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Elminster_Aumar) was said to be born in 212 DR and his *current* age is ~1267 years old. **How is this possible?**

I have read that he was a skilled and experienced human, not just in wizardry but in other classes such as warrior and rogue. He was also blessed and chosen by the Goddess of all magic, [Mystra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystra_%28Forgotten_Realms%29). Did he gain his longevity from this meeting?

***Disclaimer: I have not read the Elminster Series novels but I also couldn't find information online regarding his long life.***

Comment: I've never read them, either, but, based on what I remember from all of the Dungeon articles 'penned' by him, I thought it related to becoming one of the '[Chosen of Mystra](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Chosen_of_Mystra).'

Comment: @K-H-W - Cheers mate, that's what I also thought. Hoping someone could provide more insight :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Chosen of Mystra (and the Chosen of other deities) were immortal.  But exactly who was chosen and whether Mystra even existed has varied over the years in the Forgotten Realms plotline.  It hasn't exactly been the most reliable way to stay immortal.

However, for Elminster this seems unlikely to have been essential as the *Wish* spell is not specifically *forbidden* from extending life, and at various times (with changing rules) there have been other ways to extend life (e.g. Potions of Longevity).  Note that at least in Dragon Magazine fiction, Elminster has been known to associate with wizards from different realities (e.g. from Greyhawk), which greatly widens his potential access to life-extending magic.  (Longevity potions specifically had an effective cap of about 200 years unless combined with luck-enhancing magic.)

So it is possible at least two and perhaps three separate ways.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for adding insight into my Star Trek longevity question also.